# json_encode strange results if komma in string

Tags: php, json

I have a string including a komma (,).

When I pass this string into the json_encode function I get a wrong result

Example:

```
json_encode(["test" => "This is a, test"]);
// returns "[\"test\" => \"This is a, test\"]"
// without komma {"test":"This is a test"}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce : `echo json_encode(["test" => "This is a, test"]);`, result : `{"test":"This is a, test"}`. But if you enclose the expression in single quotes, the result is like yours : `echo json_encode('["test" => "This is a, test"]');` => `"[\"test\" => \"This is a, test\"]"`

Answer (score 0):

Check my code playground, maybe problem is not in the comma.
https://repl.it/@kallefrombosnia/KeyFastVerification

```
<?php

$comma = json_encode(["test" => "This is a, test with comma"]);

$wocomma = json_encode(["test" => "This is a test without comma"]);

print_r($comma);
print_r($wocomma);

var_dump($comma);
var_dump($wocomma);

echo $comma;
echo $wocomma;

// Only case which can cause backslashes is to encode 2x same string
echo json_encode($comma);

// "{\"test\":\"This is a, test with comma\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right! I use an old Caldav lib and ist replaces every , with \,

Thanks for your help!